# Use command-line arguments in VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I'm using the following VBS script to delete the first n number for line from a file:

```
strInputFile = "*Filename.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const intForReading = 1
Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, intForReading, False)
If Not objInputFile.AtEndOfStream Then
      objInputFile.SkipLine
Else
      WScript.Quit
End If
strContents = ""
While Not objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
      If strContents = "" Then
            strContents = objInputFile.ReadLine
      Else
            strContents = strContents & VbCrLf & objInputFile.ReadLine
      End If
Wend
objInputFile.Close
Set objInputFile = Nothing

Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strInputFile, True)
objOutputFile.Write strContents
objOutputFile.Close
Set objOutputFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

How do I change the code so that instead of a constant input file it will be an argument when I start the program via CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at wscript.arguments which provides access to the command line used to start the script.

```
if (wscript.arguments.count <> 1) then
    wscript.echo "Usage: dl2unc <drive-letter-path>"
    wscript.quit 1
end if

s = wscript.arguments.Item(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
strInputFile = "*filename.txt"
```

to

```
strInputFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
```

and the first arg would be the file name.